# Adding a database to the TFS Server Instance

Tags: team-foundation-server

I have posted a couple of questions about TFS databases over the past couple of months.  It was made clear that thou shall not modify TFS databases manually as it will void any support that we may have.

Is there any issue with adding a database to the TFS Server?  The database that I want to add will only have one table with about 50,000 rows and will be accessed a couple times a day.

I'm using TFS 2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only rule in TFS is, don't touch the databases owned by TFS. And if you've paid for the SQL Server License you can add as many other databases as you'd like. TFS will not have any issues with that, but it won't make these databases part of the backup schedule, so you'll have to do that yourself.

**AND** if you're using the 1 free SQL Server Standard license that you get with a TFS server license, you're not allowed to host any other databases on that instance other than the databases that are maintained by TFS itself.